# Technically, why is this DIV centered, when top, bottom, left and right are zero?

Tags: html, css, css-position, margin

I am learning the many ways to center an element in the middle of the screen. I just discovered the code below, and I am trying to understand the technical explanation behind how it works.

```
<body>
   <div class="square"></div>
</body>
```

```
.square{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    margin: auto;

    background-color: pink;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

At first, I thought if both top and bottom are zero, the element will be we vertically centered on the screen. Also if both left and right are zero, the element will be horizontally centered on the screen. But all this will not work without `margin: auto`. Can you help me understand how `margin` interacts with `top, bottom, left and right`?

Comment: none of the below answer are correct. Check the duplicate for the accurate explanation from the official specification.

Answer (score -1):

This div is in the center because you have set the margin to auto. what happens when you set margin to auto it will calculate the distance from all directions weather it is top, bottom, left, or right. the distance from each point will be same that's why the div is in center.

for example if we have to middle the webpage in horizontal center we give the webpage margin like this.

```
body {
margin:0 auto;
}
```

this will make the body equal distance from left and right side but it will give 0 margin on top and bottom.

Answer (score -1):

[margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aQxF.png)

The margin property is actually a shorthand property for the following individual margin properties:

- margin-top
- margin-right
- margin-bottom
- margin-left

In margin auto, the element will take up the specified width, and the remaining space will be split equally between the left and right margins, similarly for the top and bottom.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to understand what `margin: auto;` does.
by setting `margin-left: auto;` will take up the right whole space of screen and the element is slipped to the right of the screen
and `margin-right: auto;` will take up the right whole margin and element is slipped to the left
***and one point to remember is margin for top and bottom does not work***
When we use the `margin: auto;` it means we are letting our element to take up the equal margin from left and right and align itself in the center(horizontally)

Further you can use left, right, bottom and top positioning only when the `margin: auto;` is turned on

1. top: 0; //means margin from top is 0 and element is fixed to top
2. bottom: 0; //means margin from bottom is 0 and element is fixed at the bottom

and same is the case with left and right
when we use them all at once it means that we are specifying each element to stretch in every left, right, bottom, and top position which is only possible when element has width equal to the screen

So the element is aligned horizontally and vertically as well

For further guidance you can consult this documentation:
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-margin-auto/